# Css shadow entire screen length

Tags: html, css

box shadows are basically your shape blurred.

that means that at the edges the shadow is curved up.

what if you don't want that? what if your shadow is for a top bar and you don't want it to seems like it ends?

issue:

[image: issue]

desired effect :

[image: desired effect]

how do I obtain this?

html :

```
<div class="TopBar"> </div>
```

css :

```
.TopBar {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 28px black;
}
```

Am I supposed to use an absolute positioned element that's bigger than screen width or something?

Comment: Please post all the required code (HTML and CSS) to enable us to reproduce the issue you are having.

Comment: post some code.

Comment: if you have no code you should start from the basics. this link may help. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: I posted the code I have so far. there really isn't much to be expected from it.

Comment: That code does hardly reproduce what you have shown in the screenshot. Since the div is empty, it won’t even have a height ... so your code copy&pasted into a jsfiddle or something currently shows _nothing_ ... please go read up on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I don't believe there's a better box-shadow than that out of the box. I think you'll have to develop some hack like a div with 110% width. It would be easy to apply `transform : scaleX(1.1)` but it also stretches the content.

Comment: That being said, unless specifics of your broader layout make this impossible, you should be able to easily fix this by dragging the element “over the edges” a bit via a negative margin, and then offset that again by a corresponding positive padding (`margin: 0 -50px; padding: 0 50px;`). Dragging the element over the right edge might cause a horizontal scrollbar - to counter that, wrap the whole thing in an additional container element with `overflow: hidden` (and some additional padding-bottom, so that the box-shadow doesn’t get cut) - https://jsfiddle.net/crp0zan9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `spread` parameter to the shadow (not exactly the same appearance, but at least it does what you ask for):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.TopBar {
  height: 40px;
  background: #444;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 24px 16px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopBar"></div>
```

Comment: @tatsu I just read your comment to the accepted answer. I don't want to critize that answer, but "the least lines of code"  and "CSS only" definitely applies to *my*  answer: I only added the `16px` (spread) inside the `box-shadow` setting, the rest is just some code to make the whole thing visible in a snippet, since you didn't supply any other CSS code in the question...

Comment: ok, you know what you're right. upon re-reading your answer it does seem a lot simpler. my bad :(

Answer (score 1):

Fake it! You can use linear gradient and a pseudo element to get the effect you want:

```css
.TopBar {
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}
.TopBar::after {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopBar"> </div>
```

Comment: out of the three answers (all of which work and are satisfactory) this answer requires the least lines of code with zero drawbacks. I even tested transitions. confining the solution to CSS-only seems to me to be what is deserved and in the end this comes out as the least "hacky".

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pseudo-element (:before) to extend it beyond your original container and therefore, get a wider shadow :

```css
html, body { margin:0; padding: 0 }

.TopBar {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.TopBar:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #454545;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 28px #000;
  transform: scaleX(1.1);
  z-index: -1;
}
.TopBar .content {
  color: #add8e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopBar">
  <div class="content">Here's some text inside my top bar</div>
</div>
```